# nouveau: Where are module parameters stored?

Tags: kernel-module, debian-buster, nouveau

I have been trying to debug a bug with nouveau and I would like now to remove the previous setting.

Here is what I see:

```
% dmesg | grep nouveau
[...]
[    1.487361] [drm:nouveau_drm_init [nouveau]] ... debug        : PTHERM=debug,PTIMER=debug
```

Which is compatible with:

```
# cat /sys/module/nouveau/parameters/debug 
PTHERM=debug,PTIMER=debug
```

Where is this setting stored ?

I tried a naive:

```
% find /etc/modprobe.d 
/etc/modprobe.d
/etc/modprobe.d/nouveau.conf
```

which gives:

```
% cat /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau.conf
# debug nouveau
options nouveau debug="PFIFO=debug"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `nouveau` is starting from `initramfs`.

In order to change the load options for this kind of modules one need to run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

to get the setting applied.